# The most efficient way to schedule content on a website

Tags: sql

I have lots of content that needs to be published on a web site some time in the future. What's the most efficient way to publish it when the time comes?

My current implementation is in two datetime columns: `online_at` and `offline_at`.

The sql query to fetch content looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contents 
 WHERE online_at > current_timestamp 
   AND (offline_at IS NULL OR 
        offline_at < current_timestamp);
```

with an index over the `online_at` and `offline_at` columns. It works well and there are no obvious performance penalties, but I'm still wondering if there is a more efficient way to go about this. Is there a way to reduce the index to one simpler column (not a datetime, which seems expensive)?

Comment: please explain the online_at and offline_at columns

Comment: they are datetime columns, as stated in the question. online_at contains the datetime the content should appear online, and offline_at contains the datetime the content should disappear again. offline_at can also be NULL in which case the content never disappears.

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: Why do you find a datetime expensive? Performance, space, ...?

Comment: Why does a datetime seem expensive to you? This is a pretty trivial operation, and as long as there's an index on the column(s) I really can't see it impacting performance much. We probably need to know more about why you're worried. Definitely sounds like one of those times where you should go with this solution now and come back to it later if it turns out there's *actually* a problem.

Comment: While there are no obvious performance issues now, they might pop up in the future if/when traffic is heavy. I have no deep SQL knowledge, and my query seems logical to me. I was just wondering if any people proficient in SQL saw obvious problems with it. Seems it's a fine query then, and also reasonably future-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen your construction many times and I've only seen it become prohibitively slow when hitting millions of rows, so I'm not sure you should really worry about the construction.

One thing, that I haven't tried myself, but that could give you increased parallelism, is to have seperate indexes on `online_at`and `offline_at` and then using `EXCEPT`/`MINUS` (depending on your DB). In essence just use the IDs, but this could obviously be extended with the entire field list except for the dates. Ie:

```
SELECT id, header, text, ... 
  FROM CONTENT
 WHERE online_at < current_timestamp
 MINUS
SELECT id, header, text, ... 
  FROM CONTENT
 WHERE offline_at < current_timestamp
```

Comment: That's actually a very smart query. Seems like something to try when problems arise. For now it seems like overkill and I happily accept your observation that the original query is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what database you are using, but if you are using mysql, making your columns timestamps will only use 4 bytes vs 8.

Also I would suggest insuring that offline does not default to NULL or allow NULL.  Use a perpetuity date (some date in the future as the default).  You can alter the table definition and set this as the default date.  For a timestamp that date is '2037-12-31'.  For a datetime, it is '9999-12-31'.

Now unless this is going to be a large database at some point, which is probably unlikely, saving 8 bytes per row isn't that big of a deal, but you asked  ;)

If this is not a mysql question, please let me know and I'll remove this answer.  If it is, you might retag.

You can also rewrite the query to be 
    SELECT ... where NOW() between online_at AND offline_at

But again you want to eliminate the requirement that it look at IS NULL as these columns are not in the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually using this technique on a variety of systems: MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite. Personally, I am not a fan of using dummy dates like 9999-12-31 to signify a missing value. In my opinion NULL is a fine value to use when something is missing, like the offline_at in the example.

Comment: @Joost:  I respect your right to be illogical  ;)  In your system offline_at IS NULL does not mean the value is missing.  If it did no rows with offline IS NULL would appear in the result set.  You are actually using them to indicate that the article "Has no expiration date".  Since you asked --- this effectively eliminates the use of the index on offline_at, makes things slower, and in general makes the application less portable, because NULL's are generally problematic and to be avoided.  Having to add OR should be an indication to you that you are forcing the db to do more work.

Comment: You do have a point, but in the app that's on top of the database the NULL is easily handled. So in my case I am not too worried. Although I very much agree that the actual value I want to store isn't NULL, but it's "FOREVER" or something like that. But I am pretty sure that isn't in the SQL spec. :)

Comment: @Joost: that is why you pick a perpetuity date, and make it the column default value as I suggested. Because they are valid dates, all date arithmetic and comparisons work, and the indexes are utilized in queries, and you no longer need to query on IS NULL.